# Are there any books on WiX?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Are there any books on WiX?

Comment: Had I saw one there I wouldn't be asking.

Comment: Hi.. I have just launched my blog for WIX..This will slowly be updated for WIX material. Please visit http://wix-guide.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 10):

Yes! [A Developers Guide to Windows Installer XML](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849513724) (I've got it, but haven't read it yet so can't comment on the quality of the book)

However I would first say, forget about WiX initially. Your concern is Windows Installer - WiX is simply a tool to define Windows Installer databases (MSI files). WiX is no different than many other products out there, except for the fact that it doesn't try to mask any Windows Installer concepts for you. InstallShield transparently does a bunch of things that Windows Installer doesn't support via custom actions and the like, WiX forces you to think more about the Windows Installer methodology and way of doing stuff. Windows Installer is what you want to understand, WiX comes afterwards.

Second, **get a copy of [The Definitive Guide to Windows Installer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590592972).** This book is an invaluable resource for anyone looking to understand how Windows Installer (MSI) works.

Third, start with the first entry in the [UAC in MSI blog posts](http://blogs.msdn.com/rflaming/archive/2006/10/01/uac-in-msi-notes-answers-to-questions-in-comments-from-earlier-blog-posts.aspx) and you should be able to get a better grip on things. Best documentation I ever read in trying to understand elevation, permissions and all the other stuff that goes with UAC.

Once you understand Windows Installer, WiX is extremely straightforward. It's just a new language to express the Windows Installer concepts - trying to learn them at the same time can get very confusing, but if you learn MSI first then WiX it's simple!

Comment: A newer version of "A Developers Guide to Windows Installer Xml" is available.  I've read about 6 chapters and it's quite good: http://www.packtpub.com/windows-installer-xml-3-6-developers-guide/book

Answer (score 5):

There is a book now: http://www.packtpub.com/article/getting-started-with-windows-installer-xml-wix.

Before you ask, no I have not read it. :)

Comment: i have read this book. This is very useful one

Comment: Would this book also work as a general reference, or is it just for people learning WiX for the first time?

Answer (score 4):

I believe there is one in development called "The Wix Book", but right now I'm not sure any exist.

I usually point people towards this tutorial, it gives a good overview of the features and tools available:

http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/

There is also a quick introduction here:

http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2004/04/19/wix.html

Comment: +1. Also, the wix.chm file which is included into the distribution contains useful tips. Take a look at "How To" section first.

Comment: My two biggest complaints of the CHM is that 1) required attributes are often misleading as whether something is required is often context sensitive and 2) when an attribute isn't required it doesn't tell you what the default value of the attribute is so you have no way of knowing whether you would want to override it or not except by doing and then redoing.

Answer (score 2):

I found a great WiX book on amazon recently and bought it. So far, very straightforward and useful.

[http://www.amazon.com/WiX-Developers-Guide-Windows-Installer/dp/1849513724](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849513724)